# Android: Comparing json Array with SQLite Data

Tags: android, json, sqlite, comparison, arrays

I have a big Problem in my app, i need to compare a json Array with a stored data in a SQLite Database, but I tried unsuccessfully to resolve this for days, i have a the method for obtain the json Array (no problem with this) and i have a SQLiteDatabase already created, the info is the next:

"Courses" JSONArray:

```
{"Courses":[{"CourseId":4,"Rating":5.0000,"Status":-1},{"CourseId":5,"Rating":5.0000,"Status":5},{"CourseId":6,"Rating":5.0000,"Status":-1},{"CourseId":8,"Rating":4.6119,"Status":5}.. etc
```

The Database Have 1 Table with 72 records with the Next Data:
CourseID, Title, Instructor, Rating, Length, Topic, Subject & Description.

My objetive here is obtain the value "Status"(5 or -1) from the JSONArray but saving all the records contain the values "Status=5", example:

```
if(Status==5){ //save all the record {"CourseId":8,"Rating":4.6119,"Status":5}}.
```

...And later obtain from the Database the records that meet the condition "CourseId:" (String from json) == (CourseID from Database), and show this Database values into a listview (Title, Instructor, Rating, Length, Topic, Subject & Description).

Any suggestions or help would be welcome and appreciated.

Comment: you can use both data to create object and use comparator to check

Comment: suggestions or methods for Android can Help me for obtain this type of Data "JSONArray" later over of the comparison.

Comment: I suggest you google SQLite Android tutorial and use SQLite Manager FireFox Plugin to learn SQLite.

Comment: you need to make a array list of json  and arraylsit of sqlite table you want to compare compare pojo of both the arraylist

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look here: http://code.google.com/p/resting/wiki/TwoMinuteTutorial

This way you can build your JSON result into POJO's. Then you can iterate your list and persist all courses with status 5.